# NSNotification send multiple objects?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I am learning how to use NSNotificationCenter. My understanding is that for each notification, you can send a single object. Is there a way to send a notification with multiple objects or must I post a new notification for each object?

Comment: have you read the memo of the `userInfo` parameter...?

Answer (score 7):

You can pass any information you like in the `userInfo` argument of `postNotification:object:userInfo:`.

For example, you could call the method as follows:

```
NSDictionary *accountDetails = @{@"accountHolder":@"Mr John Smith",
                                 @"accountNumber":@(01234567),
                                 @"sortCode":@"01-98-34"};

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"BankDidCreateNewAccount" object:self userInfo:accountDetails];
```

Just to explain in more detail: to post notifications with an object, you'd use either

`-postNotificationName:object:` or `-postNotificationName:object:userInfo:`

In the object argument, you may only supply a single object. Typically, the `object` argument is the `notificationSender`, i.e. you would pass `self` from wherever you post the notification.

If you have registered for notifications using `-addObserver:selector:name:object:`, and you passed any value but `nil` for the `object` argument, then you will only receive notifications where the posted notification object (`object` argument in `-postNotificationName:object:`) matches the the `object` argument in `-addObserver:`.

If you pass `nil` in `-addObserver:` then the `object` value of `-postNotification:` is ignored for this particular observer.

Wow, that sounds complicated. But it's actually very simple. `object` argument must match if used in `-addObserver:`.

Use `userInfo` argument to supply more details to the notification observer.

Answer (score 1):

A notification can only have one `object`. For multiple objects it depends what you want to send them for. If each is being observed separately then yes, you need to send multiple notifications. If you just need to send context info then you should use `userInfo`.